# Drawing Text of shaped user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, gdi+, shapes

```
class starbutton : UserControl
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public override string Text { get { return base.Text; } set { base.Text = value; this.Invalidate(); } }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        SolidBrush brush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        Point[] points =
        { 
            new Point(ClientSize.Width / 2, 0), 
            new Point(0, ClientSize.Height/4), 
            new Point(0, ClientSize.Height), 
            new Point(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height)
        };
        graphics.FillPolygon(brush2, points);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

I created a custom user control to make a button using shapes. I managed to do it but I added a property so it could display text on the shape but it didn't show the text. Why it is not showing the text?

[image]

Comment: You're never painting the text.  When you override `OnPaint` you're responsible for drawing everything.

Comment: how do i paint the text on it?

Comment: @DeaDViruS Additional to Alexei's good answer, I posted my answer as an option. I'll be happy if you kindly take a look at that and find it helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only drawing strange polygon in `OnPaint` implementation and do not render any text.

Add code that renders text (i.e. using [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ftkekek(v=vs.110).aspx) after drawing polygon:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text , this.Font, 
    new Point(10, 10), SystemColors.ControlText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea for creating a shaped control, is shaping its region.

I created this control with this specifications:

- Inherited from `Button` (I saw you named it `StartButton`, so I implemented it inheriting from `Button`, you can inherit from label if you only want having `Text`)
- Has `Text` an other stuff rendering automatically
- Has `TextAlign` property so its text can be drawn inn standard alignments like other controls text.
- The areas out of green polygon doesn't belong to control anymore and click on that area doesn't handle by the control.
- The areas out of green polygon are really transparent and everything behind that area will be seen.
- Behavior of design time about region is the same as run time.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyUserControls
{
    public class StartButton : Button
    {
        public StartButton()
        {
            this.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            this.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomLeft; 
            this.Size = new Size(100, 100); 
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            this.UpdateRegion();
            base.OnPaint(pevent);
        }
        protected void UpdateRegion()
        {
            var path = new GraphicsPath();
            Point[] points =
            { 
                new Point(ClientSize.Width / 2, 0), 
                new Point(0, ClientSize.Height/4), 
                new Point(0, ClientSize.Height), 
                new Point(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height)
            };
            path.AddPolygon(points);
            this.Region = new Region(path);
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you this works as well :), exactly what i was trying to do before.

Comment: can you make a star shape?

Comment: It is not so hard, maybe need some math knowledge, I think I can.

Comment: and a circle as well if possible because i tried but i'm getting a weird shape.

Comment: @DeaDViruS Not so hard, To draw a circle you need to use `DrawEllipse` method of `Graphics` and for a Star you need `FillPolygon` as you did it before, but star is a little bit  tricky.

Comment: @DeaDViruS Have you ever asked any question about it, this discussion seems to be useful to other users too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89298/discussion-between-deadvirus-and-reza-aghaei).